# How to add fake store in shallowMount() using vue3 + typescript in jest unit tests?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I'm lost I read documentation to be able to add fake `store` in `shallowMount()` function.

In the official doc : https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html, So I implement this sample

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import ProjectItem from "@/components/ProjectItem.vue";
import { state } from "@/data/fakeStore/projects";
import Vuex from "vuex";

describe("ProjectItem.vue", () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(Vuex);

  const fakeStore = new Vuex.Store({
    state: state,
    getters: {
      projects: jest.fn(),
      skills: jest.fn(),
      skillsFromOneProject: jest.fn()
    }
  });

  const wrapper = shallowMount(ProjectItem, {
    props: {
      index: 0
    },
    fakeStore,
    localVue
  });

  it("check initialization data", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.projects).toEqual(state.projects);
    expect(wrapper.vm.skills).toEqual(state.skills);
    expect(wrapper.vm.index).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

But I can't use `createLocalVue` because I got

> Module '"@vue/test-utils"' has no exported member 'createLocalVue'.

Moreover at the line `shallowMount(ProjectItem,`

I got the following error

> No overload matches this call.
> The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'DefineComponent<{}, {}, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 4 more ..., {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptionsWithObjectProps<Readonly<ComponentPropsOptions>, {}, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 4 more ..., { ...; } | {}>'.
> Type 'DefineComponent<{}, {}, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 4 more ..., {}>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentOptionsBase<Readonly<(readonly unknown[] & { [x: number]: string; } & { [iterator]?: IterableIterator | undefined; length?: number | undefined; concat?: string[] | undefined; join?: string | undefined; ... 19 more ...; toLocaleString?: string | undefined; }) | ({ ...; } & ... 1 more ... & { ...; })>...'.
> Types of property 'setup' are incompatible.
> Type '((this: void, props: Readonly<LooseRequired<Readonly<{} & {} & {}>>>, ctx: SetupContext<{}>) => void | {} | RenderFunction | Promise<...>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((this: void, props: Readonly<LooseRequired<(Readonly<(readonly unknown[] & { [x: number]: string; } & { [iterator]?: IterableIterator | undefined; length?: number | undefined; concat?: string[] | undefined; ... 20 more ...; toLocaleString?: string | undefined; }) | ({ ...; } & ... 1 more ... & { ...; })> & ...'.
> Type '(this: void, props: Readonly<LooseRequired<Readonly<{} & {} & {}>>>, ctx: SetupContext<{}>) => void | {} | RenderFunction | Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '(this: void, props: Readonly<LooseRequired<(Readonly<(readonly unknown[] & { [x: number]: string; } & { [iterator]?: IterableIterator | undefined; length?: number | undefined; concat?: string[] | undefined; ... 20 more ...; toLocaleString?: string | undefined; }) | ({ ...; } & ... 1 more ... & { ...; })> & {...'.
> Types of parameters 'ctx' and 'ctx' are incompatible.
> Type 'SetupContext<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'SetupContext<{}>'.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2769)
> mount.d.ts(22, 25): The last overload is declared here.

So I decided to try another thing, thank's to https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#context I saw `mocks` option, so I replace wrapper by the following code

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(ProjectItem, {
    props: {
      index: 0
    },
    mocks: {
      $store: fakeStore
    }
});
```

I still have the error `No overload matches this call ...` as before.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "pixi.js": "^6.1.3",
    "v-smooth-scroll": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
```

Can you show me unit test sample that add store to `shallowMount()` ?

**UPDATE**

Store code used in the component :

```
import { Project } from "@/domain/store/Project";
import { ProjectsGetters } from "@/store/projects/getters";
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

@Options({
  props: {
    index: String
  }
})
export default class ProjectItem extends Vue {
  store = useStore();
  index!: string;
  projects: Array<Project> = this.store.getters[ProjectsGetters.projects];
  skills: string = this.store.getters[ProjectsGetters.skillsFromOneProject](
    this.index
  );

  projectOver(index: number) {
    this.projects[index].classname = "line-right";
  }

  projectLeave(index: number) {
    this.projects[index].classname = "line-left";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I used documentation for vuejs 2, so the documentation for vuejs 3 is here : https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vuex.html#testing-with-a-real-vuex-store

Here is my test

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import ProjectItem from "@/components/ProjectItem.vue";
import { projects } from "@/store/projects";
import { state } from "@/data/fakeStore/projects";
import Vuex from "vuex";

describe("ProjectItem.vue", () => {
  const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      projects: {
        namespaced: true,
        state,
        getters: projects.getters
      }
    }
  });

  const wrapper = shallowMount(ProjectItem, {
    props: {
      index: 0
    },
    global: {
      plugins: [store]
    }
  });

  wrapper.vm.projects = state.projects;
  wrapper.vm.skills = state.skills;

  it("check initialization data", () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.projects).toEqual(state.projects);
    expect(wrapper.vm.skills).toEqual(state.skills);
    expect(wrapper.vm.index).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```